# querySelectorAll javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Имеется такой код:

```
<article>
<div id="input">
  <p>
    <input id="input" />
    <button id="uah" class="active" onclick="currency='uah'; selectCurrency()">UAH</button>
    <button id="usd" class="inactive" onclick="currency='usd'; selectCurrency()">USD</button>
    <button id="eur" class="inactive" onclick="currency='eur'; selectCurrency()">EUR</button>
    <button id="rub" class="inactive" onclick="currency='rub'; selectCurrency()">RUB</button>
  </p>
</div>
</article>
```

JavaScript для него:

```
<script>
function selectCurrency() {
  console.log("Selected currency: " + currency);
  document.querySelectorAll("article div#input p button").classList.add("inactive");
  document.querySelectorAll("article div#input p button").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector("article div#input p button#" + currency).classList.remove("inactive");
  document.querySelector("article div#input p button#" + currency).classList.add("active");
}
```

При нажатии на USD вываливается ошибка.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Не могу понять, что не так?

Comment: querySelectorAll возвращает коллекцию элементов очень похожую на массив, чтобы добавить или удалить класс, надо по ней пройтись и каждому элементу добавить. А вы пытаетесь коллекции добавить.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать в стиле jQuery - сразу со множеством. На jQuery это было бы так: `$("article div#input p button").addClass("inactive")` . Ну и не понятно зачем вам такой длинный селектор `article div#input p button` : почему не `#input button`, некрасиво же? Ну и ещё - два элемента в вашем коле имеют один id `input` - это тоже нехорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelectorAll возвращает коллекцию элементов очень похожую на массив, чтобы добавить или удалить класс, надо по ней пройтись и каждому элементу добавить. А вы пытаетесь коллекции добавить. Должно быть так

```js
function selectCurrency() {
  console.log("Selected currency: " + currency);
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("article div#input p button");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var el = buttons.item(i);
    if (el.id !== currency) {
      el.classList.add("inactive");
      el.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      el.classList.add("active");
      el.classList.remove("inactive");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.inactive {
  background-color: gray;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<article>
<div id="input">
  <p>
    <input id="input" />
    <button id="uah" class="active" onclick="currency='uah'; selectCurrency()">UAH</button>
    <button id="usd" class="inactive" onclick="currency='usd'; selectCurrency()">USD</button>
    <button id="eur" class="inactive" onclick="currency='eur'; selectCurrency()">EUR</button>
    <button id="rub" class="inactive" onclick="currency='rub'; selectCurrency()">RUB</button>
  </p>
</div>
</article>
```